# how to parent follow children in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make an empty game object and added sprite render component. Then because of inconsistency `sprite renderer` and `NavmeshAgent` I was forced to create one `Emptygameobject` as child of parent `EmptyGameobject` then add `NavmeshAgent`
component.in `runtime`. I need parent `Gameobject` follow  `childgameobject`.
I write a class for `navmesh` move and I attribute it to objects by drag and drop it. look like this :

[image]

1. All the objects in this class are moving.
2. Following the child object is not done correctly.

that move class called in the following form

[image]

Comment: Post directly your code and not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Add navmesh to parent and sprite renderer to child object and move parent

Answer (score 2):

why would you want to move the child with the parent following, you can just move the parent. the child will follow and there will be no difference in functionality

Comment: my parent is a Empty game object whit sprite renderer.....after add navmesh agent my sprite It becomes vertical .....I have to use this method